# Gram-schmidt process for polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonal-polynomials, gram-schmidt

$$S = \{1, x , x^2\}$$

S is a set of orthogonal vectors.
So instead of applying the gram-schmidt process to obtain the orthonormal basis, can't we just do

$$S' = \{1/||1||, x/||x||, x^2/||x^2||\}$$

Inner product is defined by

$$\int_{-1}^{1}p(x)q(x)dx$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: An even polynomial with all coefficients of the same sign is not going to be orthogonal to a nonzero constant, because the integrand will be of one sign.

Comment: Perhaps you're confusing $\langle x, e_1 \rangle$ and $\langle x^2, e_1 \rangle$? If we apply the definition of the inner product given, we can see that the first is $0$ because we're integrating an odd function from $-1$ to $1$, but the second cannot be $0$ because $x^2$ is even.

Comment: So is orthogonality solely dependent on how the inner product is defined? I thought $x^2 = (0,0,1)$ and $1 = (1,0,0)$ --> (0,0,1) and (1,0,0) are orthogonal. @chirpyboat73

Comment: They are orthogonal with respect to the usual inner product. See, for example, Gaussian quadratures.

Comment: @SamyakJain Yes, by definition, two vectors are orthogonal if their inner product is $0$. You're thinking about using the inner product for $\mathbb{R}^n$ which says to multiply components and add, but Axler defines a different inner product at the top of the page that says to treat the two vectors as polynomials, multiply, and integrate them from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: ...and the result consists of the first three Legendre polynomials!

Comment: $\int_{-1}^{1} 1\cdot x^2 dx \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original problem, you are given a Euclidean vector space $\biggr(\mathbb{R}[x_2], (f, g):=\int\limits_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx\biggr)$, where $\mathbb{R}[x_2]$ is a space of polynomials of degree 2 or less. Note that Euclidean vector space is already endowed with a special inner product $(f, g)$. You cannot define a Euclidean vector space without specifying a particular inner product that goes along with it. So in G-S you have to use this particular inner product, by the definition of Euclidean vector space and G-S process. Specifically, given basis $\{1, x, x^2\}$, let's find the orthogonalization $\{p_1, p_2, p_3\}$.

Apply G-S:

$p_1:=1$

$p_2:=x-\frac{(x, p_1)}{|p_1|^2}p_1=x-\frac{1}{2}$. Since $|p_1|^2=(p_1, p_1)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}1dx=1$ and $(x, p_1)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}xdx=\frac{1}{2}$.

Similarly,

$p_3:=x^2-\frac{(x^2, p_1)}{|p_1|^2}p_1 - \frac{(x^2, p_2)}{|p_2|^2}p_2 =x^2-x+\frac{1}{6}$.

Thus, the orthogonal basis is $\{1, x-\frac{1}{2}, x^2-x+\frac{1}{6}\}$.

Note that I did it for the range of integration from 0 to 1. You just need to compute the same objects for the range of -1 to 1.

Comment: Thank you! I was mixing up inner product space with a normal vector space. Just to clarify, if no inner product is defined over $P_2(R)$, then $\{1, x, x^2\}$ is an orthogonal set of vectors right?